# How to compute $\lim\limits_{x \to 1^+} \left(\frac{\tan \sqrt {x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a problem with this limit, I don't know what method to use. I have no idea how to compute it.
Can you explain the method and the steps used? Thanks

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1^+} \left(\frac{\tan \sqrt {x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to  1^+}\frac{\tan \sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}&=\left(\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{\sin\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-1}}\right)\left(\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{1}{(\cos\sqrt{x-1})\sqrt{x+1}}\right)\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

By the Taylor expansion , as $u \to 0$, one has
$$
\tan u=u+O(u^3)
$$ giving, as $x \to 1^+$,
$$
\tan \sqrt{x-1}=\sqrt{x-1}+O((x-1)^{3/2})
$$ thus
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\tan \sqrt {x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}&=\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-1}\times \sqrt{x+1}}+O\left(\frac{(\sqrt{x-1})^3}{\sqrt{x-1}\times \sqrt{x+1}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}+O\left(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x+1}}\right)\\\\
&\to \frac1{\sqrt{2}}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might be instructive to present a development that goes back to "the basics" and relies on elementary tools only.  To that end, we recall from geometry that the sine function satisfies the inequalities

$$z \cos z \le \sin z\le z \tag 1$$

for $0\le z\le \pi/2$.

Rearranging $(1)$ we immediately see that $z\le \tan z$.  Furthermore, from $(1)$ we see that $\sin^2 z\le z^2$ from which it is straightforward to show that $$\cos z\ge \sqrt{1-z^2}$$ for $0\le z\le 1$.  Therefore, we have

$$z\le \tan z \le \frac{z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \tag 2$$

Now, letting $z=\sqrt{x-1}$ in $(2)$ reveals for $1 \le x\le 2$

$$\sqrt{x-1}\le \tan\left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)\le \frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{2-x}} \tag 3$$

Dividing both sides of $(2)$ by $\sqrt{x^2-1}$, we obtain for $1<x\le 2$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}\le \frac{\tan\left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{2-x}} \tag 4$$

Applying the Squeeze Theorem to $(4)$ gives the coveted limit

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to 1^+}\left(\frac{\tan\left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$$

and we are done!

Answer (score 0):

$$
\lim_{x \to 1^+} \left(\frac{\tan\sqrt{x-1} }{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)  = \lim_{x \to 1^+} \left(\frac{\tan\sqrt{x-1} }{\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt{x+1}}\right) = \lim_{x \to 1^+} \left(\frac{\sin\sqrt{x-1} }{\sqrt{x-1}} \cdot \frac{1}{\cos\sqrt{x-1}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}\right) =$$ 
$$ \lim_{x \to 1^+} \left(\frac{\sin\sqrt{x-1} }{\sqrt{x-1}} \right) \cdot \lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{1}{\cos\sqrt{x-1}} \cdot \lim_{x \to 1^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}} = 1 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$